# Generating Payroll Forms with Zend_PDF?

Tags: zend-framework, pdf-generation

Good Morning,

I'm interested in generating PDFs from my payroll website which is being built using Zend Framework.  Zend_PDF looks to be fairly intimidating in terms of the amount of work needed to generate a PDF that contains payroll data, let alone a W2 document.  Are there better tools available (thinking Smarty or FPDF?) that are compatible with Zend Framework and will generate the level of intricacy needed for a pay stub or W2?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I use html2pdf, a well done tool which converts html code to pdf files.
You can find examples here :
http://html2pdf.fr/example

It's easy to use and integrate with Zend.

Comment: Too bad they don't have an English site :)

Comment: My mistake, i forgot to give you the english version.
http://html2pdf.fr/en

And here the english documentation with a very simple example to getting started : http://wiki.spipu.net/doku.php?id=html2pdf:en:v4:accueil

Comment: Thanks for the new link.  No issues implementing this with ZF 1.11?

Comment: None.
You just need to include the library file, and then you can have fun.
Generate your html (there are rules to follow, like markup to avoid, specific markup to use for pages, ...) and then output it to a file!